# LU decomposition with PartialPivLU

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, eigen3

I have the following code in MATLAB that does an LU decomposition before trying to calculate `lamb` which I've included to give some context.

```
P=[1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9];
U=[0;1;2];
[F,J]=lu(P);
Jlamda=F\U;
lamb=J\Jlamda;
```

F is:

```
0.142857142857143   1                   0
0.571428571428571   0.500000000000000   1
1                   0                   0
```

U is:

```
7                   8                   9
0                   0.857142857142857   1.71428571428571
0                   0                   1.11022302462516e-16
```

When I try to replicate this in Eigen with the following code:

```
MatrixXd P(3, 3);
P << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9;
MatrixXd U(3, 1);
U << 0, 1, 2;

PartialPivLU<MatrixXd> lu = PartialPivLU<MatrixXd>(P);
MatrixXd J = lu.matrixLU().triangularView<UpLoType::Upper>();
MatrixXd F = lu.matrixLU().triangularView<UpLoType::UnitLower>();

MatrixXd Jlamda = F.lu().solve(U);
MatrixXd l = J.lu().solve(Jlamda);

cout << F << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << J << endl;
```

Which prints:

```
1                    0                  0
0.142857             1                  0
0.571429             0.5                1
```

```
7                    8                  9
0                    0.857143           1.71429
0                    0                  1.11022e-16
```

Whilst I can obviously handcraft a matrix to transform the rows of F in C++ to that of the F from MATLAB I am not sure how to do that dynamically.

Is `PartialPivLU` the best way to go about this, or am I missing something more trivial?

Answer (score 5):

By calling `[F,J]=lu(P)`, the resulting matrix `F` is a *permuted* lower triangular matrix. You can call the function as `[F,J,perm]=lu(P)` to receive `F` as a truly lower triangle matrix and `P` as the separate permutation matrix so that `F*J = perm*P`. By default, the line

`MatrixXd F = lu.matrixLU().triangularView<UpLoType::UnitLower>();`

using Eigen returns the true lower triangular matrix. If you want the permuted lower triangular matrix like Matlab returns, then you can store the permutation matrix in Eigen by calling `permutationP` and then multiplying this matrix by `F`.

Comment: This is almost the correct answer, except for some reason you must also call transpose on permutationP prior to multiplying by F. See below.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by DCSmith is pretty close, however it seems that you must also call transpose() on the permutation matrix in order to get the correct result:

```
MatrixXd P(3, 3);
P << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9;
MatrixXd U(3, 1);
U << 0, 1, 2;

PartialPivLU<MatrixXd> lu = PartialPivLU<MatrixXd>(P);
MatrixXd J = lu.matrixLU().triangularView<UpLoType::Upper>();
MatrixXd F = lu.matrixLU().triangularView<UpLoType::UnitLower>();
MatrixXd perm = lu.permutationP().transpose();
MatrixXd F1 = perm * F;

MatrixXd Jlamda = F.lu().solve(U);
MatrixXd l = J.lu().solve(Jlamda);

cout << perm << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << F1 << endl;
```

Prints:

```
0 1 0

0 0 1

1 0 0


0.142857 1   0

0.571429 0.5 1

1        0   0
```

Which is the same as the MatLab example